# Z-Index on various elements with fixed position

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, fixed

**Hi!**

I have recently been trying to "layer" three elements (one a, p and hr-element) with z-index and these elements are containing inside of a seperate wrapper, while i have another one for the nav (called #menu in this case), which these three elements are going to turn up hidden behind. The a-element and p-element works out fine (both of them has fixed positions), but the hr-element doesn't seem to work (note: it also has a fixed position)!

[Here's the actual site i'm working on!](http://jsfiddle.net/svz45)

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="bg">
        <div class="bg">

            <p draggable="false" id="name">&lt;Title&gt;</p>

                <div class="line">
                    <hr id="line"/>
                </div>

            <a draggable="false" href="#menu" id="title">Enter</a>


        </div>
        <!--End bg-->
</div>
<!--- End wrapper#bg -->

<div class="wrapper" id="main">
<!-- Start wrapper#main-->

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PHOTOS.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FILMS.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SITES.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PHOTOS.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FILMS.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SITES.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PHOTOS.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FILMS.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SITES.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT.</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
    <!-- End menu-->     

</div>
<!-- End wrapper#main-->  

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Bodoni;
    src:url(fonts/BodoniXT.ttf);

}

.wrapper#bg {
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 768px;
}

.wrapper#main {
    background: #FFF;
    margin: -16px auto;
    width: 768px;       
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
}

div.bg {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    width: 970px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -41px;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}   

div.bg img {
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -26.4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */


}

p#name {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Bodoni,"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 72px;    
    width: 768px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
     -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
      -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
         animation: fadein 2s;
}

.wrapper#bg .line {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;

}

.wrapper#bg .line hr#line {
    margin-left: 184px;
    position: relative;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
     -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
      -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
         animation: fadein 2s;

}

a#title {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Bodoni,"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-top: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 72px;
    width: 768px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */

}

a#title:hover {
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left: 6px;

}

<!--Slut på bg-section-->

<!--Början på menu-section-->

nav#menu {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 970px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -10px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    box-shadow:         0px -10px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

nav#menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav#menu a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    font-family: Bodoni, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: padding-left 0.25s; /*Safari and Chrome*/
}

nav#menu a:hover {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

**NOTE: I'm new to both HTML and CSS, and english isn't my primary language.**

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Code please. Also you sometimes need to make certain elements relative to make them prior over other elements.

Comment: Their position has to be fixed, because i want them to stay centered in the frame. Can i make this, even if i have position: relative; ??

Comment: Try to make only a parent element the fixed position. Then you can make a wrapper-element inside it that has position relative. Inside that wrapper you can just position absolute/relative your live away and just z-index them if needed. `<div class="fixedDiv"><div class="relativeWrapper"><!-- CONTENT --></div></div>`. You are making it hard on yourself. Good code has to be simple, not hard, especially in such an early stage of progress.

Comment: Thanks for the support and your opinion on the code, Allendar! I will reply soon if this solution works!

Comment: I've actually started from the beginning with my site. I agreed to your opinion and i've started restructurizing the whole thing!